# GitHub CODEOWNERS with routing folders

Tags: github, github-codeowners

I'm trying to assign different teams or people to various features in a Remix/React app. Remix uses `[abc]` folder names for routing, which is invalid in the CODEOWNERS file:

`/app/[id]/edit @team`

shows an error on GitHub. I tried escaping `\[id\]` and quotes `"/app/[id]"` already but that didn't do anything either.

Any suggestions?